# Creating nested dictionaries in Python using Openpyxl

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

Trying to build a dictionary in Python created by looping through an Excel file using Openpyxl, where the key is the Name of a person, and the value is a list of dictionary items where each key is the Location, and the value is an array of Start and End.

Here is the Excel file:

[image]

And here is what I want:

```
people = {
  'John':[{20:[[2,4],[3,5]]}, {21:[[2,4]]}],
  'Jane':[{20:[[9,10]]},{21:[[2,4]]}]
}
```

Here is my current script:

```
my_file = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book2.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = my_file.active

people = {}
for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
  a = row[0] # Name
  b = row[1] # Date
  c = row[2] # Start
  d = row[3] # End
  if a.value:  # Only operate on rows that contain data 
    if a.value in people.keys():  # If name already in dict
      for k, v in people.items():
        for item in v:
          #print(item)
          for x in item:
            if x == int(b.value):
              print(people[k])
              people[k][0][x].append([c.value,d.value])
            else:
              #people[k].append([c.value,d.value])  # Creates inf loop
    else:
      people[a.value] = [{b.value:[[c.value,d.value]]}]
```

Which successfully creates this:

```
{'John': [{20: [[2, 4], [9, 10]]}], 'Jane': [{20: [[9, 10]]}]}
```

But when I uncomment the line after the else: block to try to add a new Location dictionary to the initial list, it creates an infinite loop.

```
if x == int(b.value):
   people[k][0][x].append([c.value,d.value])
else:
   #people[k].append([c.value,d.value])  # Creates inf loop
```

I am sure there's a more Pythonic way of doing this, but pretty stuck here and looking for a nudge in the right direction.  The outcome here is to analyze all of the dict items for overlapping Start/Ends per person and per location.  So John's Start of 3.00 - 5.00 at location 20 overlaps with his Start/End at the same location of 2.00 - 4.00

Comment: Is `openpyxl` a requirement? Or would you be interested in a `pandas` solution?

Comment: Openpyxl is not a requirement..@jpp

Comment: In general, you should avoid manipulating a data structure like a dictionary or a list from within a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're overthinking this; a combination of default dictionaries should do the trick.

```
from collections import defaultdict
person = defaultdict(dict)

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=4):
    p, l, s, e = (c.value for c in row)
    if p not in person:
        person[p] = defaultdict(list)
    person[p][l].append((s, e))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pandas library for this. The core of this solution is a nested dictionary comprehension, each using `groupby`. You can, as below, use a function to take care of the nesting to aid readability / maintenance.

```
import pandas as pd

# define dataframe, or df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John']*3 + ['Jane']*2,
                   'Location': [20, 20, 21, 20, 21],
                   'Start': [2.00, 3.00, 2.00, 9.00, 2.00],
                   'End': [4.00, 5.00, 4.00, 10.00, 4.00]})

# convert cols to integers
int_cols = ['Start', 'End']
df[int_cols] = df[int_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')

# define inner dictionary grouper and split into list of dictionaries
def loc_list(x):
    d = {loc: w[int_cols].values.tolist() for loc, w in x.groupby('Location')}
    return [{i: j} for i, j in d.items()]

# define outer dictionary grouper
people = {k: loc_list(v) for k, v in df.groupby('Name')}

{'Jane': [{20: [[9, 10]]}, {21: [[2, 4]]}],
 'John': [{20: [[2, 4], [3, 5]]}, {21: [[2, 4]]}]}
```

Comment: As openpyxl provides columnar access this is also possible without going through a dataframe just using `itertools.groupby`.